# Child pane css style when parent pane has -fx-border-radius in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have two panes - parent pane and child pane. Child pane is inside parent pane. Parent pane has the following css rules:

```
-fx-border-color:derive(-fx-background, -35%);
-fx-border-width:1;
-fx-border-style:solid;
-fx-border-radius:4;
```

Child pane has the following css rules:

```
-fx-background-radius:25;
```

And this is one of the corner:
[image]

As you see the corner is a little pale - I mean parent border is not well seen in the very corner (left bottom corner). To solve this problem I added to child `-fx-background-radius:25` however it didn't help. How to fix it, taking into consideration I can't add padding to parent or margin to child?

Comment: I don't truly know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am curious about this part: `I can't add padding to parent or margin to child`. If you are the programmer, why can't you do either of these?

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson The answer to your question is very simple - there are reasons because of which I can't use padding or margin in this case and which are not the part of this question.

Comment: I can't comprehend that, but maybe -fx-border-radius: 4 to child would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the sample fxml considering your problem statement.

I haven't done anything special but it worked as expected

Please refer below fxml file for same.

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="129.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-radius: 4; -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-background, -35%); -fx-background-radius: 4;">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="298.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 4; -fx-background-color: white;" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: What java version and OS do you use?

Comment: its jdk1.8.0_131 and windows 7. I used javafx scenebuilder too

Answer (score 1):

try adding: `-fx-background-radius:4;` to your parent panel (same radius as border)